# Linux block device driver request ordering - RaW?

Tags: c, linux, block-device

I am writing a Linux block device driver that receives requests via a function registered with `blk_init_queue()`.

My hardware device reorders requests and as such to avoid read-after-write conflicts it is required to wait for the completion of `write(lba x)` before issuing `read(lba x)`.

My question: Does the Linux block layer keep track of RaW conflicts and it will **not** issue `read(lba x)` until it has received a request completion (via `__blk_end_request_all(req r)` ) for a preceding `write(lba x)`, or do I have to do that in my driver?

Answer (score 0):

According to the article below, Linux block device drivers are now free to reorder requests arbitrarily, the filesystem layer is responsible for avoiding hazards and implementing barriers. 
https://lwn.net/Articles/400541/

The only exception are REQ_FLUSH and REQ_FUA requests for devices that implement write-back caches. In the case these flags are set certain ordering requirements need to be enforced by the blk device driver.
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/writeback_cache_control.txt

In particular, the following ordering requirements exist:

- No write data, REQ_FLUSH - doesn't have any ordering constraint
  other than the inherent FLUSH requirement (previously completed WRITEs
  should be on the media on FLUSH completion).
- Write data, REQ_FLUSH - FLUSH must be completed before write data is
  issued.  ie. write data must not be written to the media before all
  previous writes are on the media.
- Write data, REQ_FUA - Write should be completed before FLUSH is
  issued - ie. the write data should be on platter along with previously
  completed writes on bio completion.
- Write data, REQ_FLUSH | REQ_FUA - Write data must not be written to
  the media before all previous writes are on the media && the write
  data must be on the media on bio completion.  This is usually
  sequenced as FLUSH write FLUSH.

[from the linux-fsdevel mailinglist: http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-fsdevel/msg45616.html]